# How do I set an unkown baseUrl on Nuxt.js?

Tags: javascript, nuxt.js

Sometimes I want to run Nuxt on /api/, others on /test/, /new/2021/01/01/ or just /

Is there a way to set the router baseUrl where the index is located at?

I don't want to build everytime the path changes and set it manually.

The idea is to use a Single Page Application (SPA) where the user wants to.

Thank you!

Edit:
If is there a way to set none for the baseUrl I could write it manually on app.html, then I could make it programatically, but if I leave the baseUrl blank, it sets "/".

Comment: No one knows how could I at least remove the <base> tag when setting the baseUrl?